# Delete document in Firestore with Cloud Firestore update trigger

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Firestore triggers.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

My main objective is to delete a document, "party"
when there is no one left at the party. However, I have no clue on how to do this from
a cloud firestore trigger. Here is my code:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteOnCheckout = functions.firestore.document('/parties/{documentId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const checkedIn = newValue.checkedIn;
      console.log("Array size: " + checkedIn.length);
      //If no checked in, delete document
      if(checkedIn.length == 0){
            return //Here I want to delete the document
      }else{
          //Do nothing
          return null;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try `change.after.ref` which is the document reference? Then you can do it like this `change.after.ref.delete()`. Sorry if I missing something.

Comment: My god I was so sure I had already tried that. Tried it again and it worked. 
Please write it as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `change.after.ref` which is the document reference? Then you can do it like this `change.after.ref.delete()`.